# VLC and Chrome freeze on start

Tags: google-chrome, performance, macos, vlc

Since last week I can't open **VLC** and **Google Chrome**, it freezes immediately after opening.
It's the report output for **VLC**:

```
Date/Time:       2014-01-29 23:10:52 +0330
OS Version:      10.9.1 (Build 13B42)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  18


Command:         VLC
Path:            /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC
Version:         2.1.2 (2.1.2)
Parent:          launchd [645]


PID:             2225
Event:           hang
Duration:        4.68s (process was unresponsive for 113 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           47 (100ms sampling interval)
```

Full output: http://tny.cz/18d1a0a9

Chrome also doesn't respond - could they be related?

The only thing I want is fixing this, not a fresh install of **OSX**. 
The machine is a MacBook Pro Mid2011 running OSX 10.9.1.

Comment: Reinstalling a clean OS would be a good troubleshooting step despite you saying you don't want to do that. You could install onto an external drive and first test the hardware, then next chrome and last VLC. it would rule out and narrow down some potential causes of your difficulties.

Comment: Testing hardware? it's okay. I have a windows installed on Mac also, everything works fine there.

Comment: I would say they are not related. Did it work before?

Comment: yes they were working last week.